# conda update conda: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

Tags: python, anaconda

Windows 11 x64, CMD

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))



C:\Users\donhu>
```

[image]

How to run command success?

Answer (score 0):

Run Anaconda cmd with Administrator permission.

```
conda update conda
```

[image]